# Coolite equivalent for jquery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, extjs, coolite

Does anyone know of a well-supported ASP.NET wrapper for jquery (much like the way Coolite works for ExtJS)? I have a lot of ASP.NET web forms experience and really don't like writing javascript. I've found working with raw jquery in the web forms model to be difficult (especially when dealing with animations and handling postbacks).

If not, I'll probably just dedicate myself to Coolite!

Comment: You know what I really want? I want a well-supported ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit that utilizes jquery, so I don't have to worry about getting screwed over when MSFT eventually stops supporting their existing AJAX toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery already ships with ASP.Net MVC these days.  Have you looked into that?  Not sure that it "wraps" the jQuery API per se vs. being used under the hood (I'm not sure, I don't use it).